# Using a class template in a function template with universal reference parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, gcc

According to msvc, gcc and clang, the following code is illegal:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T&& e) {
    std::vector<T> v;
    // do something with v and e ...
}
int main() {

    int i;
    f(i);
}
```

msvc yields

> xmemory0(591): error C2528: 'pointer': pointer to reference is
>   illegal

gcc and clang give similar sounding error messages. Note that the universal reference parameter `e` is not used. The compiler obviously fails to instantiate the vector `v`, complaining about it being used with a reference to `int`:

> note: see reference to class template instantiation
>   `'std::vector<T,std::allocator<_Ty>>'` being compiled
>           with
>
> ```
>     [
>         T=int &,
>         _Ty=int &
>     ]
> ```

But I can't see where the function template `f` is instantiated with a reference to `int`.

Can somebody explain the compiler errors that we see here?

Comment: Note that *forwarding reference* is now the preferred term.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When `f` is called with an lvalue `int`, `T` will be deduced as `int&`, so `v` will be a `std::vector<int&>`. This is invalid.

One way to get around this is to remove references from `T` before using it:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T&& e) {
    using value_type = typename std::remove_reference<T>::type;
    //using value_type = std::remove_reference_t<T>; for C++14
    std::vector<value_type> v;
    // do something with v and e ...
}
```

However, if you want the function to be as generic as possible, you should use `std::decay` instead of `std::remove_reference`. This will let `f` work with cv-qualified types, arrays and functions.

Comment: Though `c++11` is tagged, perhaps also suggest `remove_reference_t` just in case? It makes it a nice one-liner.

Comment: @YamMarcovic Thanks, I've added that in, although I would rather do it on two lines than one.

Comment: A note to readers: I'd like to stress that since f is a function template even the T in std::vector<T> becomes T& when f is instantiated with an lvalue, according to the rules that the answers cite. Before, my understanding was that the T in std::vector<T> cannot be different from the T in <typename T>.

Comment: @Angle.Bracket based on that comment you still don't seem to have a clear understanding; in `template<typename T>` it says that there is a *template parameter* called `T`.  The `T` in `std::vector<T>` is that same parameter.   `T` does not become `T&`.  Instead, in your example, `T` is the type  `int&`.  `vector<T>` becomes `vector<int&>` because `T` is deduced to `int&` (as you can see from your compiler error message).  You could reproduce the behaviour without invoking type deduction by trying `f<int>(i);` vs. `f<int&>(i);`.

Comment: This definitely calls for `decay`, not `remove_reference` (with or without `remove_cv`).

Comment: @T.C. Thanks, is that better?

Answer (score 7):

Scott Meyers explains in this [article](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers).

> If the expression initializing a universal reference is an lvalue, the
> universal reference becomes an lvalue reference.
>
> If the expression
> initializing the universal reference is an rvalue, the universal
> reference becomes an rvalue reference.

In your case `i` is an lvalue and so `T` is deduced as `int&`.